# How to change default images in Windows Phone 8.1 app?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, appxmanifest

I'm trying to pass certification using the Windows app cert kit but I'm getting an error due to using the default images for tiles, splash screen and logo.

I know this is because I need to replace these default images with my own but when I try to change the images in the `Package.appxmanifest` the is no option in the `Application` to change these images.

I've looked in the WMAppmanifest also but there is no option to change.

[image]

Does anyone know how I can get access to where the images are being set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you're using WP 8.1 Silverlight.

To edit those settings using the GUI, you need to double click on the WMAppManifest.xaml in the Properties folder under the solution.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found a quick fix for this by right clicking on the `Package.appxmanifest` file and selecting view in code.

I then manually changed the paths of the images from the default images to the ones I created.

```
<m3:VisualElements DisplayName="TotalTabata" Square150x150Logo="Assets\timer_icon_medium.png" Square44x44Logo="Assets\timer_icon_44.png" Description="Total Tabata is a total solution for all your interval and HIT training needs." ForegroundText="light" BackgroundColor="#464646">
```

Still not sure why the option to change them doesn't show up in the manifest designer. If anyone has a solution please post it as an answer.